# Como eu insiro números complexos em C++?

Tags: c, c++

Eu sei que já fiz uma pergunta assim antes. Foi sobre Python. Mas em C++, como se insere um número complexo?

Answer (score 2):

Em c++ tens o tipo complex. Pode ser usado da seguinte forma:

```
// 1 + 2i
std::complex<double> c(1, 2);
```

O constructor recebe dois parâmetros:

- O primeiro, a parte real do número
- O segundo, a parte imaginário

Answer (score 0):

Em C (não está na pergunta, mas está num tag) eu faço assim

```
#include <complex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    complex double x, y, z;
    x = 3.14159 - 2*_Complex_I;
    y = 2.71828182 - _Complex_I;
    z = x - 2*y; printf("x - 2y = %f%+fi\n", creal(z), cimag(z));
}
```

Podes ver o [código a funcionar no ideone](http://ideone.com/kdi9dE).

<sup>(Em C++ não faço ideia)</sup>

Comment: Nalgumas implementações de C11 podes usar as [macros CMPLX](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.3.9.3).